# Compile SoX With CoreAudio On Win7 64-bit With Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, core-audio, sox, libsndfile

I can't quite figure out how to get SoX to compile with CAF support.
I have the libsndfile compiled and in the library folder gcc looks for.
I compiled libsndfile like this:

```
./configure --build=x86_64 --disable-shared --enable-static
```

and that worked, 
I see it generates a `caf.lo` file,
but when I try to compile SoX, it fails with this:

```
checking CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h usability... no
checking CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h presence... no
checking for CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/sox/sox-14.4.1':
configure: error: cannot find coreaudio
See `config.log' for more details
```

Since this isn't a mac I'm compiling on, I expect usability to be "no", but it should find the library for CAF, shouldn't it?

The `C:\cygwin64\usr\local\lib` folder contains `libsndfile.la` & `libsndfile.a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have been tricked, by the similarity of the names *Core Audio Format* (the CAF file format) and *Core Audio* (a MacOS X sound API), into calling `configure --with-coreaudio`. (You haven’t shown your command line.) However, those two are quite unrelated, and *Core Audio* cannot be present on a Windows machine.

Just drop the `--with-coreaudio`. If you insist, you can add `--with-sndfile` instead, since as you already know, CAF is provided by libsndfile; but it shouldn’t be necessary, because SoX by default will use all available libraries.